# Extract specific text using iMacro

Tags: web-scraping, imacros

Os : ubuntu 14.04 
browser : mozilla firefox V 36.0.1
Imacro : VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX

want an iMacro code that extract to csv file  the number "118" (or 118.5) from this html code :

```
 <div class="betting_row clearfix">
    <a href="#" class="betLink cell fifty last_cell" id="3976203966" >Over 118.5 
      <strong class="odds">0.90</strong>
    </a>
</div>
```

Note : that html code appear on any live basketball game in this bet site http://www.bet.co.za/  where i want to extract the "total  points"  number  
I've tried this code:

```
 TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"betLink cell fifty last_cell" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\d\d\d\.\d/)[0]")
```

but it extract the number and the odd : " Over 118.5 0.90"
and all i want is "118"

Comment: @beresfordt  i think it's clear now : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular case this code will be helpful:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:"betLink cell fifty last_cell" EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT EVAL("'{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/\d\d\d\.\d/)[0]")
```

For more universal solution one needs to know possible patterns (or range) of the extracted value.
BTW, if you’re still interested in the script for a csv-file without quotes, contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and I’ll give it to you.

Comment: i modified my post and i still need help . 
Thanks , i sent you an email

Comment: Can you try `PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}` after the line with 'EVAL'?

Comment: It gives two popup window the first one is " point number + odd " 
and the second one is the one i need it : the " points number" .
the problem now is that when i set "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" to desactivate the popups .. it only affects on the first one and  the points number popup still appears :/